# Data from 6 ArrayLists into a single JTable - Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I have created a JTable which is populated by various arraylists which get their data from a text list using a "~" to split. The issue I am having is that the table is displaying all data from the list on a single row.  For example:

```
Column1          Column2           Column2          Column2        Column3     Column4
1,2,3,4,5        1,2,3,4,5         1,2,3,4,5       1,2,3,4,5       1,2,3,4,5  1,2,3,4,5

When I want it to display  

Column1          Column2           Column2          Column2        Column3      Column4
1                1                    1                1              1             1 
2                2                    2                2              2             2
3                3                    3                3              3             3
```

You get the idea.  From previous advice, I think the issue may be looping, but I am not sure.

Any advice would be great.

The code is below:

```
    private void table(){     

          String[] colName = { "Course", "Examiner", "Moderator", "Semester Available ", "Associated Programs", "Associated Majors"};
         DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(colName,0);
         for(Object item : courseList){
             Object[] row = new Object[6];
       //  String[] row = new String[6];    

           row[0] = fileManage.getCourseList();
           row[1] = fileManage.getNameList();
           row[2] = fileManage.getModeratorList();
           row[3] = fileManage.getSemesterList();
           row[4] = fileManage.getProgramList();
           row[5] = fileManage.getMajorList();        
           model.addRow(row);
           textArea = new JTable(model);
}
```

This is the class that has the arraylists:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileIOManagement {

     private ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
     private ArrayList<String> courseList = new ArrayList<String>();
     private ArrayList<String> semesterList = new ArrayList<String>();
     private ArrayList<String> moderatorList = new ArrayList<String>();
     private ArrayList<String> programList = new ArrayList<String>();
     private ArrayList<String> majorList = new ArrayList<String>();



     public ArrayList<String> getNameList(){
         return this.nameList;
     }

     public ArrayList<String> getCourseList(){
         return this.courseList;
     }
      public ArrayList<String> getSemesterList(){
         return this.semesterList;
     }
      public ArrayList<String> getModeratorList(){
         return this.moderatorList;
     }
       public ArrayList<String> getProgramList(){
         return this.programList;
     }
        public ArrayList<String> getMajorList(){
         return this.majorList;
     }

     public void setNameList(ArrayList<String> nameList){
         this.nameList = nameList;
     }

     public void setCourseList(ArrayList<String> courseList){
         this.courseList = courseList;
     }    
      public void setSemesterList(ArrayList<String> semesterList){
         this.semesterList = semesterList;
     }    
      public void setModeratorList(ArrayList<String> moderatorList){
         this.moderatorList = moderatorList;
     }    

       public void setProgramList(ArrayList<String> programList){
         this.programList = programList;
     }    
        public void setMajorList(ArrayList<String> majorList){
         this.majorList = majorList;
     }    

     public FileIOManagement(){
         setNameList(new ArrayList<String>());
         setCourseList(new ArrayList<String>());
         setSemesterList(new ArrayList<String>());
         setModeratorList(new ArrayList<String>());
         setProgramList(new ArrayList<String>());
         setMajorList(new ArrayList<String>());
         readTextFile();
         getNameList();
         getCourseList();
     }

      private void readTextFile(){
         try{
             Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("Course.txt"));

             while(scan.hasNextLine()){
             String line = scan.nextLine();            
             String[] tokens = line.split("~");
             String course = tokens[0].trim();
             String examiner = tokens[1].trim();
             String moderator = tokens[2].trim();
             String semester = tokens[3].trim();
             String program = tokens[4].trim();
             String major = tokens[5].trim();


             courseList.add(course);
             semesterList.add(semester);
             nameList.add(examiner);
             moderatorList.add(moderator);
             programList.add(program);
             majorList.add(major);
             HashSet hs = new HashSet();
             hs.addAll(nameList);
             nameList.clear();
             nameList.addAll(hs);
             Collections.sort(nameList);

         }
             scan.close();
         }
         catch (FileNotFoundException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }



}
```

This is the class where I need to have the JTable:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class AllDataGUI extends JFrame{   


    private JButton saveCloseBtn = new JButton("Save Changes and Close");
    private JButton closeButton = new JButton("Exit Without Saving");
    private JFrame frame=new JFrame("Viewing All Program Details");    
    private final FileIOManagement fileManage = new FileIOManagement();    
    private ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList();
    private  ArrayList<String> courseList = new ArrayList();
    private  ArrayList<String> semesterList = new ArrayList();
    private  ArrayList<String> moderatorList = new ArrayList();
    private  ArrayList<String> majorList = new ArrayList();
    private  ArrayList<String> programList = new ArrayList();    
    private JTable textArea;



     public ArrayList<String> getNameList(){
         return this.nameList;
     }

     public ArrayList<String> getCourseList(){
         return this.courseList;
     }
      public ArrayList<String> getSemesterList(){
         return this.semesterList;
     }
      public ArrayList<String> getModeratorList(){
         return this.moderatorList;
     }
       public ArrayList<String> getProgramList(){
         return this.programList;
     }
        public ArrayList<String> getMajorList(){
         return this.majorList;
     }

     public void setNameList(ArrayList<String> nameList){
         this.nameList = nameList;
     }

     public void setCourseList(ArrayList<String> courseList){
         this.courseList = courseList;
     }    
      public void setSemesterList(ArrayList<String> semesterList){
         this.semesterList = semesterList;
     }    
      public void setModeratorList(ArrayList<String> moderatorList){
         this.moderatorList = moderatorList;
     }    

       public void setProgramList(ArrayList<String> programList){
         this.programList = programList;
     }    
        public void setMajorList(ArrayList<String> majorList){
         this.majorList = majorList;
     }    



     public AllDataGUI(){
         getData();
         table();
         panels();  
            }


     public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            String[] token = nameList.get(rowIndex).split(",");
            return token[columnIndex];

        }

     private void table(){


          String[] colName = { "Course", "Examiner", "Moderator", "Semester Available ", "Associated Programs", "Associated Majors"};
         DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(colName,0);
         for(Object item : courseList){
             Object[] row = new Object[6];
       //  String[] row = new String[6];    

           row[0] = fileManage.getCourseList();
           row[1] = fileManage.getNameList();
           row[2] = fileManage.getModeratorList();
           row[3] = fileManage.getSemesterList();
           row[4] = fileManage.getProgramList();
           row[5] = fileManage.getMajorList();        
           model.addRow(row);
           textArea = new JTable(model);



//         String END_OF_LINE = ",";
//               
//         String[] colName = { "Course", "Examiner", "Moderator", "Semester Available ", "Associated Programs", "Associated Majors"};
////            textArea.getTableHeader().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
////            textArea.getTableHeader().setForeground(Color.BLUE);
//           // Font Tablefont = new Font("Details", Font.BOLD, 12);
//           // textArea.getTableHeader().setFont(Tablefont);  
//            Object[][] object = new Object[100][100];
//            int i = 0;   
//            if (fileManage.size() != 0) {
//                for (fileManage book : fileManage) {
//                    object[i][0] = fileManage.getCourseList();
//                    object[i][1] = fileManage.getNameList();
//                    object[i][2] = fileManage.getModeratorList();
//                    object[i][3] = fileManage.getSemesterList();
//                    object[i][4] = fileManage.getProgramList();
//                    object[i][5] = fileManage.getMajorList();    
//                   
//                    textArea = new JTable(object, colName);
//                }  
//            }
     }
     }



      public void getData(){      
      nameList = fileManage.getNameList();
      courseList = fileManage.getCourseList();
      semesterList = fileManage.getSemesterList();
      moderatorList = fileManage.getModeratorList();
      majorList = fileManage.getMajorList();
      programList = fileManage.getProgramList();
     // textArea.(write());
  }

    private JButton getCloseButton(){
        return closeButton;
     }     




    private void panels(){        
          JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,1));
          panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
          JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(15,0,10,10));
          rightPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(15, 5, 5, 10));
          JScrollPane scrollBarForTextArea=new JScrollPane(textArea,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
          panel.add(scrollBarForTextArea); 


          frame.add(panel);
          frame.getContentPane().add(rightPanel,BorderLayout.EAST);
          rightPanel.add(saveCloseBtn);
          rightPanel.add(closeButton);
          closeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                    {
                        frame.dispose();

                    }
        });
          saveCloseBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //saveBtn();                
                frame.dispose();

            }
        });
           frame.setSize(1000, 700);
           frame.setVisible(true);   
           frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

}

//    private void saveBtn(){
//        File file = null;
//        FileWriter out=null;
//        try {
//            file = new File("Course.txt");
//            out = new FileWriter(file);     
//            out.write(textArea.getText());
//            out.close();
//        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        } catch (IOException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
//        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "File Successfully Updated");       
//        
//  }



}
```

Comment: `From previous advice, I think the issue may be looping,` - No, that is not what was stated as the problem in your previous question. You were told several times that you can't add an ArrayList to the TableModel (what you see is a String representation of the ArrayList)!!! Read the answer that was given for the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Table]

There's probably a few ways this might be achieved, for me, I'd start by creating my own `TableModel` which would allow me to control how data was added to it and managed.

For example

```
public class ColumnBasedTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private Map<String, List<String>> columnData;
    private List<String> columnNames;

    public ColumnBasedTableModel() {
        columnData = new HashMap<>(25);
        columnNames = new ArrayList<>(25);
    }

    public void addColumn(String name, String... data) {
        columnNames.add(name);
        List<String> colData = columnData.get(name);
        if (colData == null) {
            colData = new ArrayList<>(26);
            columnData.put(name, colData);
        }
        colData.addAll(Arrays.asList(data));
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        int rows = 0;
        for (List<String> data : columnData.values()) {
            rows = Math.max(data.size(), rows);
        }
        return rows;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return columnNames.get(column);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Object value = null;
        String name = getColumnName(columnIndex);
        List<String> data = columnData.get(name);
        if (data != null) {

            if (rowIndex < data.size()) {
                value = data.get(rowIndex);
            }

        }
        return value;
    }

}
```

This simple model maintains column data in a `Map`, keyed to the column name.  Each element in the `Map`'s value is a row in the column...

Runnable example...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class SimpleTableExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SimpleTableExample();
    }

    public SimpleTableExample() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                ColumnBasedTableModel model = new ColumnBasedTableModel();
                model.addColumn("Column 1", createColumn(1, 5));
                model.addColumn("Column 2", createColumn(6, 9));
                model.addColumn("Column 3", createColumn(11, 3));
                model.addColumn("Column 4", createColumn(16, 8));
                model.addColumn("Column 5", createColumn(21, 15));
                model.addColumn("Column 6", createColumn(26, 7));


                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(new JTable(model)));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    protected String[] createColumn(int startAt, int count) {

        String[] values = new String[count];
        for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
            values[index] = Integer.toString(startAt + index);
        }
        return values;

    }

    public class ColumnBasedTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private Map<String, List<String>> columnData;
        private List<String> columnNames;

        public ColumnBasedTableModel() {
            columnData = new HashMap<>(25);
            columnNames = new ArrayList<>(25);
        }

        public void addColumn(String name, String... data) {
            columnNames.add(name);
            List<String> colData = columnData.get(name);
            if (colData == null) {
                colData = new ArrayList<>(26);
                columnData.put(name, colData);
            }
            colData.addAll(Arrays.asList(data));
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            int rows = 0;
            for (List<String> data : columnData.values()) {
                rows = Math.max(data.size(), rows);
            }
            return rows;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            return columnNames.get(column);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            Object value = null;
            String name = getColumnName(columnIndex);
            List<String> data = columnData.get(name);
            if (data != null) {

                if (rowIndex < data.size()) {
                    value = data.get(rowIndex);
                }

            }
            return value;
        }

    }

}
```

**A `FileIOManagement` `TableModel` example**

```
public class FileIOTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    public static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES = {
        "Course",
        "Name",
        "Moderator",
        "Semester",
        "Program",
        "Major",};

    private FileIOManagement manager;

    public FileIOTableModel(FileIOManagement manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        int row = manager.getCourseList().size();
        row = Math.max(row, manager.getMajorList().size());
        row = Math.max(row, manager.getModeratorList().size());
        row = Math.max(row, manager.getNameList().size());
        row = Math.max(row, manager.getProgramList().size());
        row = Math.max(row, manager.getSemesterList().size());
        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 6;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return COLUMN_NAMES[column];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

        List<String> data = null;
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                data = manager.getCourseList();
                break;
            case 1:
                data = manager.getNameList();
                break;
            case 2:
                data = manager.getModeratorList();
                break;
            case 3:
                data = manager.getSemesterList();
                break;
            case 4:
                data = manager.getProgramList();
                break;
            case 5:
                data = manager.getMajorList();
                break;
        }

        Object value = null;
        if (data != null) {
            if (rowIndex < data.size()) {
                value = data.get(rowIndex);
            }
        }

        return value;

    }

}
```

Comment: I have added my class that contains the ArrayLists.  What would be the best way to implement what you have suggested?

Comment: So, you have 6 ArrayLists, I used 6 arrays, what do you think might need to do to marry the two together?

Comment: A good programmer and a bottle of whiskey? :P

Comment: Well, I don't drink ;) - I'm helping my 2 year old cook dinner, I'll see what I can do after tea ;)

Comment: You're game... My two year old would eat off the floor if I let her.

Comment: I have added the class that houses the JTable.

Comment: Or perhaps something like the added example

Comment: You are a beautiful human being.  Now I just have to figure out how to stop the Array out of bounds exceptions when I edit and save.

Comment: If I add the class you wrote, how can I call it in the appropriate class?

Comment: To do what?  Basically you must pass it a valid instance of `FileIOTableModel` and it will do the rest.  If you need to update `FileIOTableModel` externally, you will need to be able to tell the model that it's changed so it can notify the table

Comment: I was just asking because it is it's own class and the frame that will house the table lives in the AllData Class.

Comment: You should be able to call it like any other class

Comment: I don't think you realise just how dumb I am when it comes to programming.

Comment: I think you under sell your self ;)  Experienced is earned by tripping over and picking yourself up again

Comment: When I try private FileIOTableModel table; = new FileIOTableModel(); is it throwing me a constructor cannot be applied to given types error.

Comment: Well, my example required you to pass it an instance of `FileIOManagement` via the constructor

Comment: I am pathetically lost.  Thanks anyhow.

Comment: `FileIOManagement manager = new FileIOManagement();` then `model = new FileIOTableModel(manager);`

Comment: where are you getting model from?  It tells me it cannot find symbol

Comment: Sorry, thought you pre-declared it. You could use `FileIOTableModel model = new FileIOTableModel(manager)` or declare it as an instance variable